# Change owner of relation in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I just started using PostgreSQL and have problems in changing the ownwer of a table. I have a database `postgis_in_action` and a user `postgis_in_action`. As I worked as postgres user and as well as postgis_in_action user my tables `ch01.highways` and `ch01.highways_staging`have different owners `postgres` and `postgis_in_action`. They are in the same schema `ch01`. I checked the following command in psql as postgres user in my database `postgis_in_action`:

```
ALTER TABLE ch01.highways_staging OWNER TO postgis_in_action
```

Do I have to add or modify something if I want to change the owner for `ch01.highways_staging` to `postgis_in_action`?

In psql I don't get any error message and the result of the command is that the ownwer remains `postgres`.

I'm logged in to my database with user postgres because I wanted to have the priviledge to change the owner of a table/relation.

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

A generic reason that affects those new to `psql` is forgetting the semicolon at the end of the command, so that it doesn't get executed. Otherwise your command looks good and should do what you want.